# Not able to retrieve Solidity event in JavaScript

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

I have my sample contract as:-

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Storage {
  uint256 storedData;

  event print(uint256 store);

  function set(uint256 data) public {
    emit print(data);
    storedData = data;
  }

  function get() constant returns (uint256) {
    return storedData;   
  }
}
```

After setting the value from geth console and mining it, when I use get function to check the value it returns the correct value which was set earlier.
However when I try to get the event logs with the following code:-

```
var eve = instance.print({sender:eth.coinbase},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: "latest"});
var allValues = eve.get();allValues[allValues.length - 1].args;
console.log(allValues[allValues.length - 1].args.store);
```

Here instance is the contract instance, It shows the error as cannot access member args of undefined.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum StackExchange.You can't call events from outside the contract - they are meant only for the contract to emit internally. So you can only trigger the event by calling your `set` function.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen He's trying to _read_ the event from outside the contract (after calling `set`).

Comment: I believe the issue is `{sender: eth.coinbase}`. I'm not sure what that's supposed to be doing or if it's having any harmful  effect, but I would try removing it. (Just use `{}` instead as the first parameter, since you don't want to filter at all.)

Comment: Hm, ok thanks for the heads-up, I'm not so familiar with web3 so disregard my comment :)

Comment: @smarx I have tried that as well, still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine for me. I tried to match your code as closely as possible using Node.js and `ganache`. Here's my full (working) test code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const compiled = solc.compile(`
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Storage {
  uint256 storedData;

  event print(uint256 store);

  function set(uint256 data) public {
    emit print(data);
    storedData = data;
  }

  function get() constant returns (uint256) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
`, 0).contracts[':Storage'];

web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => {
  web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];

  const contract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(compiled.interface));
  contract.new({ data: compiled.bytecode, gas: 3000000 }, (err, instance) => {
    if (instance.address) {
      instance.set(42, (err, txHash) => {
        instance.print().get((err, logs) => {
          console.log(logs[0].args.store.toString()); // OUTPUT: 42
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your code looks pretty close to what I am trying. I still don't know why mine gives the above error.

Comment: I was hoping you could compare your code to mine and try to find a difference. If that's not helping, perhaps you can share the rest of your code/methodology. (E.g. share how you're compiling and deploying the code, your calls to `set` and `get`, etc. Everything someone would need to replicate your test.)

Comment: For deploying contract, we are using .js file as follows:
var interfaceContent = eth.contract(ABI)
var byteCode = "0x" + "BYTE_CODE"
var c = interfaceContent.new({from:eth.accounts[0],data:byteCode,gas: 4700000}, function(e, contract){
    if(e) {
      console.error(e); 
      return;
    }
    
    if(!contract.address) {
      console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

    } else {
      console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
      console.log(contract);
    }
})

Comment: Then in the geth console I am deploying the contract as loadScript(filenam.js) and waiting till the contract gets mined to get the address.
After that I am getting contract instance as instance = eth.contract(ABI).at("ADDRESS")
For setting a value, instance.set(4123) and waiting for the transaction to get mined.
Now after this if I check the value as var v = instance.get() and console.log(v), it shows me the new value. However if I try to read the event as mentioned above , it says :-
TypeError: Cannot access member 'args' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:1